# How to prove that set of prime number such $p\equiv 7 [12]$ is infinite?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, arithmetic-progressions

We have $n \ne 3k$ with $k\in \mathbb{N}$ and the integer $4n^2+3$. I think the first thing is to prove that this integer has a prime factor $p\equiv 7 [12]$.

I don't have idea to begin.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: hint: any prime factor $p$ of $4n^2+3$ must be $1\pmod{3}$, since $-3$ is a square mod $p$ (quadratic reciprocity).

Comment: @ArtW I have to use the chinese lemma ?

Comment: Is $p\equiv 7 [12]$ a new notation for $p\equiv 7 \bmod 12$? I've never seen it before.

Comment: @TonyK french notation !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The proof below is a variant of Euclid's proof that there are infinitely many primes, or more precisely that given a finite collection of primes, there is a prime not in the collection.

Let $p_1,p_2,\dots, p_t$ be primes of the form $12k+7$. Let 
$$N=(2p_1p_2\cdots p_t)^2+3.$$
We will show that $N$ has a prime divisor $p$ of the form $12k+7$.

Note that if $p$ divides $N$ then $-3$ is a quadratic residue of $p$. By quadratic reciprocity it follows that $p\equiv 1\pmod{3}$. (Here, depending on what has been proved in your course so far, there may be some detail to fill in.)

So $p\equiv 1\pmod{12}$ or $p\equiv 7\pmod{12}$. But the prime divisors of $N$ cannot be *all* of the shape $12k+1$, else $N$ itself would be of the shape $12k+1$, and it isn't.

We conclude that  $N$ has a prime divisor $p$ of the shape $12k+7$. It is clear that this $p$ cannot be equal to any of the $p_i$, and the result follows.

Appendix:  Non-QR proof that $N$ will have no prime factors with shape $6k-1$

Suppose that there exist whole numbers $P, k$ such that $q=6k-1$ is prime and

$P^2\equiv -3\bmod q$  Eq. 1

Then we also have

$P^2\equiv (P+q)^2\bmod q$

and either $P$ or $P+q$ will be odd.  Therefore for some whole number $m$

$(2m+1)^2\equiv -3\bmod q$

Expanding and collecting:

$4m^2+4m+4=4(m^2+m+1)\equiv 0\bmod q$

As $4$ is prime to $q$ we divide by that factor and continue:

$m^2+m+1\equiv 0\bmod q$

$(m^2+m+1)(m-1)=m^3-1\equiv 0\bmod q$

$m^3\equiv 1\bmod q$

$m^{6k}=(m^3)^{2k}\equiv 1\bmod q$  Eq. 2

Now Fermat's Little Theorem forces $m^{6k-2}\in\{0,1\}\bmod q$.  Clearly $m^{6k-2}\equiv 0\bmod q$ contradicts Eq. 2.  If instead $m^{6k-2}\equiv 1\bmod q$ then Eq. 2 forces $m\in\{-1,1\}\bmod q$.  The latter then implies

$P^2\equiv (2m+1)^2\in\{1,9\}\bmod q$

which contradicts Eq. 1.  Since all possibilities for $m$ lead to a contradiction the assumption of Eq. 1 cannot be true for any $P, k$.

Comment: If $p$ divides $N$, $p$ divides $4$ and $3$ ?

Comment: If $p$ divides $N$, then $p$ must be odd, since $N$ is odd. And $p$ cannot be $3$. For if $3$ divides $N$ then $3$ divides $4(p_1\cdots p_t)^2$, which is impossible, since all the $p_i$ are of the shape $12k+7$.

Comment: I don't understand "$p\equiv 1\pmod{3}$ so $p\equiv 1\pmod{12}$ or $p\equiv 7\pmod{12}$" ?

Comment: Any number congruent to $1$ modulo $3$ is congruent to one of $1$, $4$, $7$, or $10$ modulo $12$. Since $p$ is odd, it cannot be congruent to $4$ or $10$ modulo $12$, which leaves the possibilities $p\equiv 1\pmod{12}$ and $p\equiv 7\pmod{12}$.

Comment: One last thing, how do you deduce that $-3$ is a quadratic residue of $p$ ?

Comment: If $p$ divides $N$, then $N\equiv 0\pmod{p}$, so $(2p_1\cdots p_t)^2\equiv -3\pmod{p}$. It follows that there is a solution of $x^2\equiv -3\pmod{p}$, namely $x=2p_1\cdots p_t$.

Comment: Of course thank you !

Comment: @Maman: You are welcome.

Comment: I have a wonderful proof without QR that $N$ cannot have a $6k-1$ prime factor, but it is too large to fit into the comments.  See the edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions tells you that there is infinitely many primes $p$ such that

$$p=a\pmod k$$

if $a\wedge k=1$.

And in your case you have $7\wedge 12=1$ so you're good.

Comment: Is $a\wedge k$ that a new notation for $\gcd(a,k)$? I've never seen it before.

Comment: In France we often use that instead of $\text{gcd}(a,k)$, and sometimes we even use $(a,k)$. I didn't know it wasn't commonly use !

Comment: @TonyK I also think it is rare in this context, but it is logical! The natural numbers form a lattice under divisibility, and $a\wedge b$ is a common notation for [meet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_and_meet) - just what the doctor ordered here :-)