# Without using Dirichlet's theorem, show that there are infinitely primes congruent to $a$ mod n if $a^2\equiv 1\,(\!\bmod\; n)$

Tags: field-theory, prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory

Without using Dirichlet's theorem, show that there are infinitely primes congruent to $a \bmod n$ if $a^2\equiv 1(\!\bmod\; n)$. I'd prefer an answer with $Z_{p^2}$ elements if there exists one.

Comment: See [this article](https://mast.queensu.ca/~murty/murty-thain2.pdf). I ran into it when doing my homework before asking [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3214509/11619). The upshot there was about limiting the cases where the technique applies.

Comment: Mind you, you should try and motivate the question a bit more. See [our guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619).

Answer (score 3):

This is a now classical result by Murty:

> A Euclidean proof exists for the arithmetic progression
> $a \bmod n$ iff $a^2 \equiv 1 \bmod n$.

An account can be read in the paper [Primes in Certain Arithmetic Progressions](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.facm/1229442627) by Murty and Thain. See also [How I discovered Euclidean proofs](https://mast.queensu.ca/%7Emurty/euclidean.pdf) by Murty.

See also [Euclidean proofs of Dirichlet's theorem](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/dirichleteuclid.pdf) by Keith Conrad.