# Is $Z$ compact for the topology for infinitude of primes?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I know $\mathbb{Z}\subset \mathbb{R}$ is not compact for the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$. [In $\mathbb{R}$, compact=closed and bounded, and $\mathbb{Z}$ is not bounded]

How about the topology for the infinitude of primes? i.e., topology generated by $s(a,b) = \{a+nb|n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$.

---

First I know $B= \{ s(a,b)|a,b \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{Z}$ and furthere $s(a,b)$ is both open and closed [$\because s(a,b) = \mathbb{Z} \setminus \cup_{j=1}^{a-1} s(a,b+j)$].

Note that $s(0,1) = \mathbb{Z}$, so if we consider $s(a,b)$ as an open set of $\mathbb{Z}$, then it seems for me $\mathbb{Z}$ is compact[because it can cover by one open set $s(0,1)$] in this topology, but I am not sure whether my approach is valid or not.

Is my approach correct? or is there any other approach to see whether $\mathbb{Z}$ is compact in this topology?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The approach is not valid. All sets, compact or not, can be covered by a single open set: the space itself. You need to consider all possible covers of $\Bbb{Z}$ by other open sets, and show that you can reduce these to a finite subset.

That said, $\Bbb{Z}$ is not compact. Indeed, $\mathcal{U}_p = \{pn : n \in \Bbb{Z}\}$ is open for all primes $p$, and so
$$\{5n + 1 : n \in \Bbb{Z}\} \cup \{5n - 1 : n \in \Bbb{Z}\} \cup \bigcup_{p \text{ prime}} \mathcal{U}_p$$
is an open cover of $\Bbb{Z}$ by the fundamental theorem of arithmetic. But, since [there are infinitely many primes of the form $5n + 2$ or $5n + 3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3648511/how-to-prove-there-is-infinite-prime-numbers-of-form-5n3-without-dirichlet-th), and each of these primes appear exactly one open set in this union, this union has no proper finite subcover.