# Proving that $7n+3$ is prime infinitely often?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The Question is:
"Prove that there are infinite values of natural $n$ for which $7n+3$ is prime.

**Edit**: I have realised that this is a direct consequence of Dirichlet's Theorem, but the proof of this theorem is beyond me at the moment.

Is there any simple/elementary way to prove this statement?

Comment: I think you mean *infinitely many* values of natural $n$.  Do you mean $5n+3$ or $7n+3$?  Either follows from [Dirichlet's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions)

Comment: This is pretty much the same as saying "Prove that $n$ is prime for infinitely many $n$s". This is obviously true.

Comment: Meant $ 7n+3$ sorry..

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Thank you for the reference. I did not know of this theorem..

Comment: @talbi I do not see how it is obvious nor do I understand the way you have reframed the problem could you please elaborate?

Comment: [Euclid's Theorm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_theorem) proved that there exists infinitely many prime numbers. So, there exists infinitely many $n$s, for which $n$ is prime. Of course, for $\alpha n + \beta$ this is not as simple, and requires Dirichlet's Theorem.

Comment: @AdityaSharma:  You're welcome.  You might be interested in [this article](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/dirichleteuclid.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An elementary proof along the lines of Euclid's proof exists for the arithmetic progression $a \bmod n$ iff $a^2 \equiv 1 \bmod n$. Since $3^2 \not\equiv 1 \bmod 7$, there is no such proof.

Here are some references:

- [Primes in Certain Arithmetic Progressions](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.facm/1229442627) by Murty and Thain.
- [How I discovered Euclidean proofs](https://mast.queensu.ca/%7Emurty/euclidean.pdf) by Murty.
- [Euclidean proofs of Dirichlet's theorem](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/dirichleteuclid.pdf) by Keith Conrad.

Comment: Adapted from https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3346456/589