# Coprimality of integers $36k-1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

What is the simplest proof one can think of (perhaps as close as possible to the standard Euclidean one) that there are infinitely many primes of the form $36k-1$?

If you consider something like $36p_1p_2\ldots p_n - 1$ then there would a prime factor of the form $4m-1$, but it might not be congruent to $(-1)$ mod $9$.

More generally, my aim is to give an elementary proof that there is an infinite sequence $a_1, a_2, \ldots$ of positive integers such that GCD$(36a_i - 1, 36a_j - 1) = 1$ for $i\neq j$.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Showing that infinitely many primes occur in that sequence may not have such an elementary proof, but your question about the gcd does, as your can use the chinese remainder theorem to construct such a sequence inductively

Comment: For an elementary proof, see https://doi.org/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.122.01.48

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3346456/589

Comment: @Ihf  is it possible to access the article freely?